# Tile an Image in a Compositor

Tags: image, compositing-nodes

Is it possible to tile an image in the *Compositor*? I would like to use the compositor to tile an image and preview in live what the final "tiled" render will be like.

[image]

**EDIT2:**
As noted in @ayoreis's comment, I want to obtain a result like this:

[image]

**@vklidu:** I realized that I needed to scale down to `0.10`. However, the input image is very small, so the image is very pixelated:

[image]

However, I found a solution to avoid that (let me know if it's better): create via an empty texture a full-sized image, and then alpha over the (usually non scaled) version. Moreover, I can still use the scale factor to zoom more or less in my picture:

[image]

**Problem solved, thanks!** (I'll accepted the first answer that provided the first part of this solution)

Comment: Do you mean like tiling a texture like this: https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/blue-square-tiled-texture-background_53876-63563.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg

Comment: @AyoReis Exactly

Comment: On @vklidu answer as on mine too, you need to change the scale on the transform node.

Comment: BTW when used image as texture for shader (Material for object in 3D scene) it is repeated by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be working fine for me ...

[image]

Note: in a case you want to fit tiles into *Render Dimension* ...

- ad *Scale* node, switch to *Render Size* and
- use *Mix* node to combine outputs of Scale node and Transform nodes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Note that both `Wrapping: Both Axes` and `Scale: 0.1` are important here. However in my case it was not enough because the initial image was very small (so the output was pixellated). I solved that issue by adding an empty texture below (using alpha over), cf my edit. I don't need anymore `scale`, but I can still use this parameter to zoom in/out in the high resolution image. Thanks!

Comment: I used Scale node with Render Size coordinates ... I will check your solution later :)

Comment: Thanks for your edit, interesting trick to obtain a white image!

Comment: Ha :) it seems like your Texture node does the same ... so the same trick :) I thought  with Absolute I can specify dimension independently from Render, but I can't ...

Comment: Yes, the idea is the same. But I don't think it's possible to produce an image independant (or bigger) than the render, which is very sad… In case you know a trick I'd love to hear that!

Comment: Sure you can just instead of scale or texture node add big image ... But it would be more flexible to change render dimension directly (or percentage).

Answer (score 2):

I have used this node setup many times.
You could even make a custom node to control it better.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is very close to vklidu but he was first (still, +1 ;-) ), so I'll accept their answer (and indeed I missed the scale parameter the first time, thanks!). This solution suffers from the same issues when the input image is small. But the same solution I put in edit applies.

Answer (score 0):

You can do "something" like tiling like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, however it seems very tedious to create whole tiling that way... But vklidu solution makes it easier to use.